# What is the Yahoo openid discovery endpoint

Tags: python, openid, yahoo

It used to be http://yahoo.com, but it is failing for me with DiscoveryFailure in python OpenID library (since today, I wasn't testing this earlier). Also this fails if you try to use the SO login with a yahoo button, so I am thinking it probably changed recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed it was down a few hours ago.  It isn't working for any RP I've tried... except for zoho.com

I viewed their source and saw they are using **https://me.yahoo.com**, which works.

Yahoo either made a mistake in a recent site change, or forgot to tell anyone (including themselves).  [http://openid.yahoo.com/](http://openid.yahoo.com) still says to use "yahoo.com" as your openid.

Comment: https://me.yahoo.com/ is more secure than just "yahoo.com" anyway, since it uses HTTPS for the whole authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The problem only occurs on *some* yahoo servers - look up IPs for yahoo.com, and during YADIS resolution, some will work, and some won't. So that's why it works in some places and not others.

Per Yahoo ( http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OpenID-General-Discussion/http-www-yahoo-com-returns-404-depending-on-headers-/1329169111466-34212409-d649-4154-8dd6-a19e04a6d02d ), it seems their suggestion is to use https://me.yahoo.com/ instead

Answer (score 0):

Is Openid url for Yahoo  https://me.yahoo.com only. I thought it is 
 http://me.yahoo.com/profile-name . profile-name is chosen by the user at the time of selection of his openid url.